# gatsby-plugin-mdx with rehype-autolink-headers only working with wrap option

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, mdxjs, gatsby-plugin-mdx

I am trying to get my site setup with Gatsby + MDX. I am looking at the documentation [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-mdx/#rehype-plugins) and want to make use of the `autolink-header-option`. I have tried using the rehype and remark plugins for this, but I can only get the Rehype plugin to work and only with the `wrap` option. I would much prefer the GitHub (default) style with the link coming before the title.

I am using the below config in `gatsby-config.js` and cleared `.cache` and `public` after updating the file to be sure nothing was cached. Also I am not getting any errors, everything builds and runs successfully, there just is not any link to the headers.

```js
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
  options: {
    rehypePlugins: [
      // To pass options, use a 2-element array with the
      // configuration in an object in the second element
      require("rehype-autolink-headings"),
    ],
  },
},
```

#### UPDATE

After trying multiple configurations, the way I was able to get it working as expected was with a different plugin config.

```js
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
  options: {
    gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [ `gatsby-remark-autolink-headers` ],
    plugins: [ `gatsby-remark-autolink-headers` ],
  },
}
```

Both `gatsbyRemarkPlugins` and `plugins` are required as per: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/15486

Answer (score 2):

The [README](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-autolink-headings#remark-autolink-headings) for `rehype-autolink-headings` mentions that:

> This package works with headings that have IDs. One way to add IDs to headings is by using remark-slug before this plugin.

Changing your config to the following should fix it:

```js
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
  options: {
    rehypePlugins: [
      require("rehype-slug"),
      // To pass options, use a 2-element array with the
      // configuration in an object in the second element
      require("rehype-autolink-headings"),
    ],
  },
},
```

In fact, the documentation you linked to has this additional `require` line as well, but it doesn't clarify what it is used for.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was not seeing that the id is required, so was trying without the `rehype-slug` plugin. Have you used this/have it working? When I set this up, I get an `<a>` tag being applied but it has no children so cannot be clicked. In the end, I changed to use `gatsby-remark-autolink-headers` as updated in my original post above.

Comment: To wrap the heading in the `<a>` tag, I think you need to specify the `wrap` option that you had earlier: `[require("rehype-autolink-headings"), { behavior: "wrap" }]`.